# length of a SQL query having foreign and special characters

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have some text field ..which accept normal characters as well as foreign and special characters..
and the maximum size of that field is varchar(200)..

when i try to submit that field in DATABASE it's giving error that length exceeded 
below is the input that i gv in the text field

"125 LONDON WALL ß°CN°-KÂ¦Ã?rberki Ã?Ã¡zy TÃ©rÃ¡ã~ã®ð´+¢a´+¢´+¢´+¢ß-äâ§2ªáriüøÃ³næáriÑÃ³3 ½ãÿeã©ãädgåüd?OrÜ÷iujfijfoi3cjwjciowjciow1839¯¯¯¯¯¯shjfhvsf"

when i checked the length of this query string .it is 148 characters long 
but while updating the DATABASE .. it's giving the error.. that length exceeded and it's showing the actual length as 205 .as the limit was 200 characters.

So, is there is any method to check this actual length in sql ...while checking through other functions .i.e length ..it's giving 148 as length..

i am trying this in SQL developer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the max size of the field, I guess it is not 200 char but 200 bytes.. extended ascii characters may take more than 1 bytes to store. So either you can alter the table to increase the max size as varchar2(200 char).

Comment: yeah ..thanks ..the characters like '-' could take more then 1 byte to store .but my question is...is there any length method which would return the length as 205...

Comment: yes there is function "lengthb" which will return length in bytes.